# Rails - Enable some frameworks later in the project (ActiveStorage, ActionMailer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following the book **The Rails Way 7**... The authors teach some extra parameters when initializing a new project, and basically they skip *ActionMailer*, *ActiveStorage* and others, and say they add later in the project, if needed.

I was curious to see how can you enable those frameworks later in a project, so I've tried by my self, unsuccessfully.

I've tried add the *ActiveStorage* Framework by uncommenting the *require "active_storage/engine"* in the *application.rb* file, inside *config.rb*. After that, I runned the command `rails active_storage:install`, it successfully created the migrations, but the project still lacking the `active_storage` configurations, like the ones on the *environment* files and the *storage.yml* file...

Do I have to add those configurations by my self or I'm missing something? If that's the case, it's not a good thing to skip those frameworks before hand...

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes. You have to add them manually. What you can do is create a new branch in GIT and then run `rails new` command again with the `-f` option to overwrite existing files. Then merge the necissary changes into your master.

Comment: Good strategy, thanks pal!

Comment: You can also just run it without the -f option and it will ask you what you want to do for every file conflict.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add file storage.yml in config folder and add some configurations like this:

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

development:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

In example, now you can add association to one of your model and load files:

```
has_one_attached :file
```